# What does 'ad tantam mollem' refer to in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, sentence-translation, new-latin, latin-to-english-translation

This is from an explanation of the six Ptolemaic statements, the one that concludes that the world is round (*terram esse rotundam*).

> Terra tamen ob duritiem non potuit perfectam rotunditatem adipisci:
>   sed montium eminentiae, aut valles ad tantam mollem collatae non
>   sentiuntur.

*– [Opuscula Mathematica (1625), Francesco Maurolico, bottom of p. 7](https://books.google.com/books?id=qZI8AAAAcAAJ&dq=Opuscula%20Mathematica&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q=Opuscula%20Mathematica&f=false)*

Here's what I have so far:

The land, however, because of its hardness, cannot acquire perfect roundness, but the prominences of mountains and valleys are not perceived...

...compared to such softness?

What softness? I don't see any softness mentioned in the paragraph. I know what it *should* mean: compared to the magnitude of the Earth's diameter. But how does *mollis* mean that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that it says [*molem*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1010056), not *mollem*.
Therefore I suggest this translation:

> *montium eminentiae aut valles ad tantam molem collatae non sentiuntur*
>   <del>valleys or eminences of mountains are not observed to be collapsed into such a shapeless mass</del>
>   valleys or eminences of mountains combined are not observable in comparison to such a large mass

Thanks to the commenters for the improved translation!